# Download images with multiprocessing ThreadPool, FileNotFoundError?

Tags: python, download, multiprocessing, filenotfounderror

I have a list (tuple), where is local path and img url. Works fine until now.

On Python 3.11 and Windows 11 still works well (no error at all), but on Ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.11 throwing FileNotFoundError.

I'm downloading more then 30 images, but i will cut off the list here.

I can't figure out what I'm missing?

/media/hdd/img/ directory exists with 755 permission.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import os
import requests

list2 = [('/media/hdd/img/tt24949716.jpg', 'https://www.cdnzone.org/uploads/2023/01/29/Devil-Beneath-2023-Cover.jpg'), 
('/media/hdd/img/tt11231356.jpg', 'https://www.cdnzone.org/uploads/2023/01/29/Beneath-the-Green-2022-Cover.jpg'), 
('/media/hdd/img/tt13103732.jpg', 'https://www.cdnzone.org/uploads/2023/01/29/The-Offering-2022-Cover.jpg'), 
('/media/hdd/img/tt14826022.jpg', 'https://www.cdnzone.org/uploads/2023/01/29/You-People-2023-Cover.jpg'), 
('/media/hdd/img/tt18252340.jpg', 'https://www.cdnzone.org/uploads/2023/01/29/Carnifex-2022-Cover.jpg')]


def download_images(list):
    results = ThreadPool(8).imap_unordered(fetch_url, list)
    for path in results:
        print(path)

def fetch_url(entry):
    path, uri = entry
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        r = requests.get(uri, stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(path, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r:
                    f.write(chunk)
    return path
```

`>>> download_images(list2)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in download_images
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 930, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 196, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/context.py", line 113, in SimpleQueue
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 341, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error: if I create `/media/hdd/img` on my system, your code runs without error and downloads all five files into that directory.

Comment: It's really crazy, i have no idea why this error. Thank you @larsks.

Comment: What is your environment? Are you really running CPython on Ubuntu, not in a container? The stack trace says it failed to create a semaphore, an abnormal behavior on a normal Linux environment.

Comment: Yes native CPython, no containers or anything similar. Because this is really abnormal, i am trying to find another solution with multiprocessing if is possible.

Comment: Try ```python3 -c "import multiprocessing; l = multiprocessing.Lock()"``` in a terminal. If it fails, your OS is broken. Reboot or reinstall the OS.

Comment: And you need to comment like ```@relent95```, to notify a commentor like me.

Comment: @relent95 i have tried your command in terminal. No error at all, nothing.

Comment: Are you running under a Linux on a shared server provided by an ISP? On my ISP (HostMonster) you cannot create a multiprocessing pool or a semaphore or a `multiprocessing.Lock`.

Comment: Then it seems to be out of scope of SO. Anyway if you want to go on, install ```strace``` package and try ```strace python3 your_test_code.py 2>&1 | grep shm``` and post the result.

Comment: Sorry @relent95 , Booboo and larsks, I was busy to answer. After many trying i decide to reinstall Ubuntu and now is ok. Thank you all for help.